# Mosaico Extension Disabled in CiviSpark Pro

Tags: mosaico

I just set up CiviCRM Spark Pro, which says that it comes with Mosaico. However, when I go to create a new mailing, the option is not there. When I go to Administer > Settings > Extensions, Mosaico is listed as disabled. How do I enable it? If I click update, I'm only given the option to cancel, not to update.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SE!  For Spark issues, you may find the spark channel on https://chat.civicrm.org is more responsive.